# INSERT e UPDATE em relacionamento n:m no MySQL

Tags: mysql, modelagem, entidade-relacionamento

Preciso criar um relacionamento n:m no mysql, segue meu exemplo:

Tenho uma tabela chamada `empresas` e outra `representantes`. Uma empresa pode ter mais do que um representante, e um representante pode pertencer a mais de uma empresa. Neste caso, o melhor relacionamento que se encaixa para este problema, é o relacionamento n:m.

No relacionamento n:m, existe uma terceira tabela unindo o representante e uma empresa. Como posso fazer um INSERT e um UPDATE nesta terceira tabela de forma recursiva, sem duplicar os registros, sabendo que ao cadastrar uma empresa, eu tenho vários representantes, e vice-versa?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Poste o código das tabelas ou seu diágrafa de modelagem.

Comment: Postei a imagem agora.

Answer (score 2):

Eu não sei se entendi bem a necessidade, mas acho que seria:

```
insert into empresas_has_representantes (empresas_id, representantes_id) values (<id da empresa>, <id do representante>)
```

A forma de persistência destes dados depende muito do que voce está usando pra gerenciar sua camada de data access.

No hibernate, por exemplo, existe um tipo de relacionamento @ManyToMany que trata isso pra voce automaticamente. Alguma coisa a respeito voce le [aqui](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/)

Se voce usa JDBC puro, ou acesso ao banco puro, voce precisa iterar seus dados e tratar isso de forma manual, usando a query que eu postei acima pra colocar as relações.

Obviamente antes de persistir a relação, voce precisa persistir as empresas e/ou os representantes.

Quanto a duplicidade, voce pode garantir via banco, inserindo uma constraint de unique das duas colunas. Mais informações [aqui](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp)